# Unable to retrieve cookie after I set it in the browser in next.js13

Tags: authentication, cookies, http-headers, middleware, next.js13

In Next.js v13 I was trying to work with auth, and I want to store my JWT token in cookie, I was able to store it, but I am unable to retrieve it, I tried it with multiple libraries (for eg: cookie, js-cookie, cookies-next) even tried it with cookie from "next/headers", but still unable to retrieve it in both server components and client components.

"app/api/auth/loginUser/route.js"

```js
import User from "@/app/_models/User";
import connectDB from "@/app/lib/connectdb";
import { AES, enc } from "crypto-js";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { sign } from "jsonwebtoken";
import { serialize } from "cookie";

const MAX_AGE = 60 * 60 * 24 * 2;

export async function POST(request) {
    try {
        connectDB();

        const { email, password } = await request.json();
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });

        if (!user)
            return new NextResponse(
                JSON.stringify({
                    success: false,
                    message: "Invalid credentials",
                })
            );

        const dycPassword = AES.decrypt(
            user.password,
            process.env.CRYPT_SECRET_KEY
        ).toString(enc.Utf8);

        if (dycPassword !== password) {
            return new NextResponse(
                JSON.stringify({
                    success: false,
                    message: "Invalid credentials",
                })
            );
        }

        const token = sign(user.toObject(), process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY, {
            expiresIn: "2d",
        });

        const setCookie = serialize("userToken", token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
            sameSite: "strict",
            maxAge: MAX_AGE,
            path: "/",
            httpOnly: false,
        });

        return new NextResponse(
            JSON.stringify({
                success: true,
                message: "Welcome!!!",
            }),
            { status: 200, headers: { "Set-Cookie": setCookie } }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        return new NextResponse(
            JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: error.message }),
            { status: 500 }
        );
    }
}
```

"app/api/auth/me/route.js"

```js
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req) {
    try {
        const cookieStore = cookies();
        const token = cookieStore.get("userToken");

        console.log(cookieStore.getAll(), token);

        return new NextResponse(
            JSON.stringify({ success: true, token: token }, { status: 200 })
        );
    } catch (error) {
        return new NextResponse(
            JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: error.message }),
            { status: 500 }
        );
    }
}
```

"app/page.jsx"

```js
import React from "react";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export const dynamic = "force-static";

export default async function Page() {
    const token = cookies().get("userToken");
    const data = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/me", {
        method: "POST",
    }).then((data) => data.json());

    console.log(data);

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>{token}</ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Above code can store the cookie but cant retrieve it. All I get from the console.logs are empty object, array or undefined

Dependency List :

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.17",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "cookie": "^0.5.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.5.3",
    "next": "latest",
    "next-themes": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-switch": "^7.0.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
    "sass": "^1.68.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "latest",
    "eslint": "latest",
    "eslint-config-next": "latest",
    "postcss": "latest",
    "tailwindcss": "latest"
}
```

UPDATE : 
so I was experimenting with the headers, and it turns out headers are not sent to the page the where I need the cookie, When I make a request with the ThunderClient (VS code extension), i was able to get the cookie i set in the thunderClient but in the browsers like chrome and edge, headers are just empty, their is no cookie or anything, so to check that I created a middleware and console.log the headers, so in the middle ware all the things are present but, they are not being sent to the server component ("app/page.js") where i need them.

middleware.js

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export async function middleware(request) {
    console.log(request.headers.get("cookie"));
    return NextResponse.next({
        request: {
            headers: new Headers(request.headers),
        },
    });
}

// See "Matching Paths" below to learn more
export const config = {
    matcher: "/",
};
```

Headers I get in the "app/page.js" :

```js
HeadersList {
  cookies: null,
  [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(0) {},
  [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
}
```

Headers I get in the "app/api/auth/me/route.js" :

```js
HeadersList {
  cookies: null,
  [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(10) {
    'accept' => { name: 'accept', value: '*/*' },
    'accept-encoding' => { name: 'accept-encoding', value: 'gzip, deflate' },
    'accept-language' => { name: 'accept-language', value: '*' },
    'cache-control' => { name: 'cache-control', value: 'no-cache' },
    'connection' => { name: 'connection', value: 'keep-alive' },
    'content-length' => { name: 'content-length', value: '0' },
    'host' => { name: 'host', value: 'localhost:3000' },
    'pragma' => { name: 'pragma', value: 'no-cache' },
    'sec-fetch-mode' => { name: 'sec-fetch-mode', value: 'cors' },
    'user-agent' => { name: 'user-agent', value: 'undici' }
  },
  [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: [
    [ 'accept', '*/*' ],
    [ 'accept-encoding', 'gzip, deflate' ],
    [ 'accept-language', '*' ],
    [ 'cache-control', 'no-cache' ],
    [ 'connection', 'keep-alive' ],
    [ 'content-length', '0' ],
    [ 'host', 'localhost:3000' ],
    [ 'pragma', 'no-cache' ],
    [ 'sec-fetch-mode', 'cors' ],
    [ 'user-agent', 'undici' ]
  ]
}
```

Also, this is how I am redirecting to home page :

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (email == "" || password == "") {
        toast.error("Fill all the fields");
        return;
    }

    const res = await fetch("api/auth/loginUser", {
        method: "POST",
        cache: "no-store",
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    }).then((data) => data.json());

    if (res.success) {
        toast.success(res.message);
        router.push("/");  // <-------------redirect
    } else {
        toast.error(res.message);
    }
};
```

This is how cookie is stored in the edge :
[Image of cookie stored in the edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpt4q.png)

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `export const dynamic = 'force-static'` and cookies() at the same time. According to [this NextJS docs page](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#dynamic):

> Force static rendering and cache the data of a layout or page by forcing `cookies()`, `headers()` and `useSearchParams()` to return empty values.

The only solution for you is to either change the method (maybe use `sessionStorage` for storing the token?) or rendering to something different than `force-static`. Although I'm well aware that `force-static` has nice advantages for loading time (since the page is fully static and can be cached), however any usage of `headers()`, `cookies()` etc. is pointless, as empty values will be returned.